# preventDefault in Javascript stops sending email

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I'd like to ask for a little help. I saw something in jQuery but I need Javascript. For our purpose I've created simple form. With preventDefault I don't get any mail, when I delete preventDefault, I get mail with all data from form but without validation process but the validatoin function is still there. Thank you for help.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const nameInput = document.querySelector("input[name='username']");
const emailInput = document.querySelector("input[name='email']");
const subjectInput = document.querySelector("input[name='subject']");
const messageInput = document.querySelector("textarea[name='message']");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    checkInputs();
    e.preventDefault();
});

const checkInputs = () => {
    if(!nameInput.value) {
        showError(nameInput, "Field cannot be blank!");
    }
}

const showError = (input, message) => {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const errorMsg = formControl.querySelector("p");
    formControl.classList.add("error");
    errorMsg.innerText = message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically submit the form only if there is no error.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const hasError = checkInputs();

    if (!hasError) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

const checkInputs = () => {
    let hasError = false;

    if(!nameInput.value) {
        hasError = true;
        showError(nameInput, "Field cannot be blank!");
    }

    return hasError;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Martin, from the MDN page:

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

If you let the event on a **button (default type submit), an input of type submit, or a form**, it will send the email, that's the default action. It will validate nothing, just send the email.

You should ***preventDefault that event, validate everything you want, and sending the email using a fetch to a php script***, or any other valid method.

Another drawback is that if you don't prevent the default, it will refresh the browser...

Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default event of your submit handler and this is submitting the form. So in your case you always prevent the form from getting submitted as this is not related to your validation function. But you can pass the event object to your validation function and only prevent the default when your form doesn't pass the validation, for example:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    checkInputs(e);
});

const checkInputs = (e) => {
    if(!nameInput.value) {
        showError(nameInput, "Field cannot be blank!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

I'd then also merge the submit handler and the checkInputs function what would leave you with:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    if(!nameInput.value) {
        showError(nameInput, "Field cannot be blank!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: You're more than welcome, feel free to accept this answer as it helps other SO members to sort the questions in answered and unanswered.